# Move inside absolute div with scrolling

Tags: css

I have one div with `overflow: scroll` and a lot of text. Then second div inside with `position: absolute` and 100% height and width. Is it possible to do, when you scroll down, inside div also moves down so it always covers whole visible view of outer div, with only css or I'll need to use javascript?

Here's an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/y8h9E/2/) in which you can see, that scrolling down, inside div is left at the top.

CSS:

```
.test1 {
    position: relative;
    height: 200px;
    width: 500px;
    overflow: scroll;
    background: green;
}
.test2 {
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0.5;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: red;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="test1">
    <div class="test2"></div>
    Lot of text
</div>
```

Comment: Im not sure i understand the question correctly, but if you are trying to manipulate the two areas (window & div) simultaneously you will need javascript.. Is that what you mean ?

Answer (score 0):

is this what you want? [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/y8h9E/3/)

```
.test1 {
    position: relative;
    height: 200px;
    width: 500px;
    overflow: scroll;
    background: green;
}
.test2 {
    position: fixed;
    opacity: 0.5;
    height: 185px;
    width: 485px;
    background: red;
}
```

Comment: Wont this just stop the content being scrollable at all ? Therefore never being able to read the content ?

Comment: mainly scrollbar with range is form 14px to 18px so we can reduce with and height of div accordingly